# Print label on Zebra browser printer

Tags: c#, zebra-printers

Zebra browser print is nice feature. I have able to print label from any browser app like Chrome, Firefox or even from the Postman api by sending API requests. Printer is connected through USB.
My problem is that I can not able to print the same from any windows app (Wpf/Winform). I have tried the TCP IP print with this code

```
        NetworkStream ns = null;
        Socket socket = null;

        try
        {
            string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
            int port = 9100;
            var printerIP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress), port);

            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Connect(printerIP);

            ns = new NetworkStream(socket);

            byte[] toSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(zpl);
            ns.Write(toSend, 0, toSend.Length);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (ns != null)
                ns.Close();

            if (socket != null && socket.Connected)
                socket.Close();
        }
```

But it is not working.
Also tried to send data from API

```
   var data =
            "{\"device\":{\"deviceType\":\"printer\",\"uid\":\"Zebra test printer\",\"provider\":\"com.zebra.ds.webdriver.desktop.provider.DefaultDeviceProvider\",\"name\":\"Zebra test printer\",\"connection\":\"driver\",\"version\":3,\"manufacturer\":\"Zebra Technologies\"}}, \r\n\"data\":\"^XA ^FT230,45,1 ^A0N,28,28 ^FD $1.00^FS ^XZ\"";

        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:9100/write"), new StringContent(data)).ConfigureAwait(false).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("success");
        }

        var responseContent = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        MessageBox.Show(responseContent);
```

However this API code is working perfectly from any browser based app or from Postman

Here is my Browser print setting

[image: Browser print settings-Zebra]

Please let me know how can I print from the windows app?

Comment: 1. The fact that your application has a UI doesn't seem relevant to your question. 2. It seems unlikely that you've used both WinForms and WPF UI frameworks to develop your application, even if it was relevant. 3. What is the response you get when the request isn't successful? 4. Have you compared the raw request you're sending from Postman vs .NET using a tool like Telerik's Fiddler?

Comment: @John, 
1. the image I have attached is not my application but the Zebra browser settings window. 
2. I want to print it from any windows apps like wpf or winform. Any one will work.
3. I have got empty response from the API but that is success full.
4. Yes I have checked that. That is same

Comment: Responding to 2: No, you want to print it from C# code. The fact that your application has a UI isn't relevant to the question because your print code isn't UI-dependent. If you replace `MessageBox.Show` with `Console.WriteLine`, it could just as easily be a console application, right? For the purposes _of this question_ it simply isn't relevant information. It's not what you're having trouble with. Right?

Comment: Anyway, I'm not sure about the sockets code as I don't have much experience with dealing with zebra printers. I do have a lot of experience with HTTP (I'm a backend HTTP-based API developer) and if it's working through Postman then your request from .NET is certainly different in some way. You say you've checked, but have you actually looked at the raw Postman request in Fiddler, and compared it to the raw .NET request, or did you just check that the .NET request looked OK? If it's the latter then that's not enough to say the .NET request is OK.

Comment: Were you able to solve it? I wanted to create a Zebra-printing .NET Core application, but Zebra's current (Nuget) SDK is not working correctly with .NET Core (known issue). Then I had the idea, I could try to connect my .NET Core application with the browser print. Thus, any solution very welcome!